# Postman gives 401 Unauthorized -"spring boot security"

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, postman, user-roles

I'm trying to configure Spring Security on a Spring Boot application as follows and as a result  Postman gives 401 Unauthorized ,please can anyone help me to solve this error

**controller**

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.entity.User;
import com.example.demo.service.UserService;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")

public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @PostConstruct
    public void initRoleAndUser() {
        userService.initRoleAndUser();
    }


    @PostMapping({"/registerNewUser"})
    public User registerNewUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userService.registerNewUser(user);
    }
    @GetMapping({"/forAdmin"})
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('Admin')")

    public String forAdmin(){
        return "This URL is only accessible to the admin";
    }

    @GetMapping({"/forUser"})
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('User')")

    public String forUser(){
        return "This URL is only accessible to the user";
    }

}
```

**configuration**

```
package configuration;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtService;

    @Override
    @Bean

    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.cors();
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate", "/registerNewUser").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpHeaders.ALLOW).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        ;

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired

    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(jwtService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

**JwtService**

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.dao.UserDao;
import com.example.demo.Util.JwtUtil;
import com.example.demo.entity.User;
import com.example.demo.entity.JwtResponse;
import com.example.demo.entity.JwtRequest;



import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Service
public class JwtService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    public JwtResponse createJwtToken(JwtRequest jwtRequest) throws Exception {
        String userName = jwtRequest.getName();
        String userPassword = jwtRequest.getUser_code();
        authenticate(userName, userPassword);

        UserDetails userDetails = loadUserByUsername(userName);
        String newGeneratedToken = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

        User user = userDao.findById(userName).get();
        return new JwtResponse(user, newGeneratedToken);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userDao.findById(username).get();

        if (user != null) {
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                    user.getName(),
                    user.getUser_code(),
                    getAuthority(user)
            );
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
        }
    }

    private Set getAuthority(User user) {
        Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        user.getRoles().forEach(role -> {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getRoleName()));
        });
        return authorities;
    }


    private void authenticate(String userName, String userPassword) throws Exception {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName, userPassword));
        } catch (DisabledException e) {
            throw new Exception("USER_DISABLED");
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new Exception("INVALID_CREDENTIALS");
        }
    }
    
}
```

I use postman to test and when I do a GET to "http://localhost:8080/forAdmin", I get an error **401 Unauthorized**

Comment: why do you send `POST` request for  `http://localhost:8080/forAdmin`?  Your controller has been mentioned it iss a `GET` request . `@GetMapping({"/forAdmin"})`

Comment: yes ,in the postman i put it GET and i have the same probleme ,thanks for your answer

Comment: Since you have `@RequestMapping("/api")` the endpoint would be `http://localhost:8080/api/forAdmin`

Answer (score 1):

You must load the user into memory from the database, and it should be converted to UserDetails. The user details has Roles, or Authorities. It dependes what you choose. Maybe these articles can help :)

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database

https://www.baeldung.com/role-and-privilege-for-spring-security-registration

Comment: i didn't understand what do you mean exactly but i think i do that in my class JwtService ,thanks for your answer and i will be happy if you can more explain to me your idea please